# cmake для статических библиотек с общим базовым классом

Tags: c++, cmake

Я делаю маленький проект, результатом которого должны быть две статические библиотеки. Дерево проекта выглядит так:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── base
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├──── base.h
│   └──── base.cpp
├── Test1
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │       └────  set(PROJ1 test1)
│   │              project(${PROJ1})
│   │              set(HDRSRT ../base/base.h test1.h)
│   │               set(SRCSRT ../base/base.cpp test1.cpp)
│   │              find_package(Qt5Core)
│   │              set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
│   │              add_library(${PROJ1} STATIC ${HDSRT} ${SRCSRT})
│   │              target_link_libraries(${PROJ1} Qt5::Core)
│   ├──── test1.h
│   └──── test1.cpp
└── Test2
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├──── test2.h
    └──── test2.cpp
```

Тесты имеют общий базовый класс, base. Проект успешно собирается, и, даже работает. Но, если я пробую использовать две библиотеки олдновременно, получаю ошибку multiple definition методов базового класса. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ситуацию.

Comment: Вынесите определение базового класса в третью бибилотеку.

Comment: Когда  базовый класс вынесен в свою библиотеку, конечный пользователь (программа) при линковке не видит реализации базового класса.

Comment: ¿Может вы эту третью библиотеку не линкуете?